# Json serializing also class name?

Tags: json, vb.net

Hi everyone I must serialing a list in json as following

```
{  
   "ListOfStructures":[{  
      "structure":{  
         "One": "0",
         "Two": "two0"
      },
      "structure":{  
         "One": "0",
         "Two": "two0"
      }
   }]
}
```

In this moment I obtain this result instead:

```
{  
   "ListOfStructures":[ 
      {  
         "One": "0",
         "Two": "two0"
      },
      {  
         "One": "0",
         "Two": "two0"
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see, there is no name of the list item, but I need it...

Following the vb.net object I have to serialize, and that (perhaps) must be modified to obtain the desired result:

```
    Public Class MyObj

        Private _listOfStructures As List(Of Structure)
        Public Property ListOfStructures() As List(Of Structure)
            Get
                Return _listOfStructures
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As List(Of Structure))
                _listOfStructures= value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class

    Public Class Structure
        Private _one As String
        Public Property One() As String
            Get
                Return _one
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _one = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _two As String
        Public Property Two() As String
            Get
                Return _two
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _two = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
```

How can I obtain also the name of the object inside the list?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is invalid Json: every property in an object should have a unique name. In your example you have 2 **structure** properties.

I would advise to add an extra property to each object, returning the name of the type:

```
public string typeName { get { return this.GetType().Name; } }
```

Comment: mm... I understand... but I do not need another property with the type of the object.. In that case I could use a `JsonSerializerSettings` setting `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All`...
But if you say that the Json is not valid, I should talk with the person asked me that structure

Comment: Please note that even the example of what you are getting now is invalid (and probably a cut&paste error): there are two extra {} parenthesis inside the ListOfStructures array.